# Why Bar chart is not showing the data in AnyLoic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I created a bar chart as shown in image below
[image]

As you can see in value section I have this code/condition

```
time(MONTH) == scenario.ModelStopTime?(double)staticData.DynamicgymActualCapacityPercentage/100
:(double) delayGym.size() / scenario.Cpar_GymCapacity
```

Now lets say **ModelStopTime = 12** so when its 12th month according to the condition it should show `(double)staticData.DynamicgymActualCapacityPercentage/100` value but that is not the happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
(double)staticData.DynamicgymActualCapacityPercentage/100
```

It seems like the variable given above don't have any value when the chart gets updated automatically.
So what you can do is make sure you update the variable first. Once the variable have value in it  do `chart.updateData();`.

This way your condition in the chart value property will work just fine.